# Specifying schema in cloud function that uploads csv's to bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

'm encountering an issue with a Cloud Function that triggers upon the addition of a new CSV file to my Cloud Storage bucket. These CSV files are downloaded from a third-party database for my company, ensuring consistent column structures. However, I face a challenge with the "price" column, where the format varies between INTEGER and FLOAT.
[sellprice in SECOND CSV added with INTEGER type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C59lG.png)
[sellprice in FIRST CSV added with FLOAT type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DeEH.png)

In my first file, some values are FLOAT, while the second upload consists only of NUMERIC types. This inconsistency led to an error, resulting in a failure to upload the new CSV to the BigQuery table.

I'm looking for guidance on whether there is a more suitable data type that can handle both NUMERIC and FLOAT values effectively. Additionally, I would like to know how to specify this data type in the code snippet below. It seems the available resources focus on autodetecting schemas rather than allowing me to define my own.

**Here's the relevant portion of my code:**

```
import os
import logging

import functions_framework

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

# Triggered by a change in a storage bucket
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def create_bigquery_table(cloud_event):
    data = cloud_event.data

    # Configurations
    bucket_name = data['bucket']
    file_name = data['name']
    dataset_name = 'data'
    table_name = 'table'
    
    # Initialize Google Cloud clients
    storage_client = storage.Client("project")
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client("project")
    
    # Construct the URI for the uploaded CSV
    uri = f'gs://{bucket_name}/{file_name}'
    
    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client("project")
    
    # Set table and dataset reference
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_name)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_name)
    
    # Define BigQuery job config for loading the CSV
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    job_config.autodetect = True  # Auto detect schema

    # Create a load job to create the table and load data
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri, table_ref, job_config=job_config
    )  

    # Wait for the load job to complete
    load_job.result()

    logging.info(f'Table {table_name} successfully created and data loaded from {uri}.')
```

**Here is the error:**
[BadRequest: 400 Provided Schema does not match Table livdatatest:tc1_data.tc1_table. Field lwtrades_sellprice has changed type from FLOAT to INTEGER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYqCL.png)

I do not know what to try next.